# Protractor Failed: element not interactable in vue2-editor

Tags: vue.js, protractor, e2e-testing

I am using **'protractor'** for testing my web application.
I add **'vue2-editor'** in my project, I want to write something in the editor and save data.
this is the html that generate by Vue :

```
<div id="quill-container" class="ql-container ql-snow">
    <div class="ql-editor ql-blank" data-gramm="false" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Add Note...">
        <p>
            <br>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="ql-clipboard" contenteditable="true" tabindex="-1"></div>
    <div class="ql-mention-list-container" style="display: none; position: absolute;">
        <ul class="ql-mention-list"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my test code :

```
describe('When you save a note', function () {
      beforeAll(function () {
          browser.get('http://example');
          element.all(by.css(" [id='quill-container'] > div.ql-editor.ql-blank")).click();
          element.all(by.css(" [id='quill-container'] > div.ql-editor.ql-blank")).sendKeys('Some Notes add here');
          element(by.css("[id='add-note-btn']")).click();
          browser.sleep(1000);
      });
      it('You must see your note at the current page', function () {
         expect(element(by.xpath('//p[text()="Some Notes add here"]')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
       });
});
```

When I execute the code, Protractor gives this message :

> Failed: element not interactable

What should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there are four reasons why an element is not interactable.

1) Timing - the time it takes for elements to load. For this, you need to check how to use implicit an explicit wait

2)Check if the element is in a frame

3) Incorrect locator

4) Wrong implementation of responsiveness. This still stems from no 3). Some websites have only one code turned on for mobile and web versions. So, the element will have more than one instances when you check the xxxxx.size. You will have to search through the list for the one whose display != none.

Comment: what happens if element is in a frame?